# UITextField - not set new frame (at animation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I want, that searchField deformation to `targetFrame`.

**#1 This not result:**

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)bar
{
    UITextField *searchField = [bar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    CGRect targetFrame =  CGRectMake(-50, 0, 200, 30);
    searchField.frame = targetFrame; //not result

    return YES;
}
```

**#2 Incorrect, but transform:**

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)bar
{
    UITextField *searchField = [bar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    searchField.frame = CGRectMake (10, 0, 200, 50); //must differ from CGRectZero

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 3.0
                     animations: ^{

                     CGRect targetFrame =  CGRectMake(-50, 0, 200, 30);
                     searchField.frame = targetFrame; 

    }];

    return YES;
}
```

Then using #2, searchField start animation, but to default size (not to `targetFrame`).

I want, that searchField transform to `targetFrame`.

**PS**

`searchField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;` not result

Answer (score 0):

Try the below block:

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect targetFrame =  CGRectMake(-50, 0, 200, 30);
                         searchField.frame = targetFrame; 
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

   }];
```